# Lion/Mountain Lion Mission Control used with CTRL+# (10.6 Spaces-like)

Tags: macos, mission-control

Is there a way to still use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> (e.g. <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, ...) to switch to a particular Desktop? In Spaces' parlance: to a particular Space? I have difficulties swiping the trackpad and could use the old shortcut?

Also: Could I configure a particular App to open in a particular Desktop number, like in Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Lion**, by default, will switch to a particular Desktop if you hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+*Desktop's Number*. Go to **System Preferences / Keyboard / Shortcuts / Mission Control** and check if you've overwritten this shortcut.

Yes, you can configure a particular App to open in a particular Desktop. To do so just:

1. Navigate to that particular Desktop.
2. Open the App you want to assign, if its already not on the Dock, and right click on it.
3. A contextual menú will show up. Under **Options** you'll see a submenu called *Assign to* and three different options. *All Desktops, This Desktop* or *None*. Select *This Desktop*.

Comment: It's Mountain Lion and I first need to create all the Desktops and then individually assign the shortcuts (CTRL+1, CTRL+2, ...). Absurd!!!